# What does Amber Gated mean?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I am reading an Employment Offer and there are case studies to illustrate the Code of Conduct, Breachs and Outcomes. If someone knows what **amber gated** means it would be much appreciated, eg:

*The breach:*
• Mr A breached policy by failing to protect confidential information and putting sensitive market information at risk

*The outcome:*
 • Mr A received a written warning and was ***amber gated***

---

Edit: My guess is that "it is an issue/mistake/problem picked up before it became a red flag", a term used to describe a formal slap on the wrist, yet I dont understand why in the above example Mr A was given **both** a written warning AND ***amber gated***

Here is another example:

*The breach:*
• Miss B breached policy by sending confidential information to a public domain (Hotmail account)
• Confidential customer information was put at risk of being intercepted while in transit electronically
• XYZ company information should only be stored on the XYZ network. Miss B breached policy by saving XYZ information to her personal computer

*The outcome:*
• The email sent to the Hotmail account was detected through XYZ’s computer surveillance system and Miss B was requested to explain why she had sent confidential information to her personal email address
• Miss B was made aware this is a breach of policy and was amber-gated

Comment: I've never heard the phrase or anything like it, and Google turns up nothing useful.  It must be some kind of punishment short of firing (otherwise a 'warning' makes no sense), but who knows what. If it's company-specific, it might be defined in a glossary or something earlier in the manual.

Comment: `I've never heard the phrase or anything like it`

Me neither.

But how about "red-carded"?

If so, amber gated might be a synonym for "was put on probation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a traffic-analogy from the *OGC Gateway™ Review* planning process.

Typically there are gateways (or gates) representing critical requirements, they will be assigned a red, amber or green (RAG) status, representing the severity of issues in achieving that requirement. My workplace (a large one), apparently like the place referred to above, uses such a system for managing the yearly employee review. Completion of training requirements, adherence to regulations, career plan discussion with boss, completion of reviews with staff reporting to you etc. are all gates the employee needs to "pass through" in order the complete the review. To speak informally, to set an employee's status on one of their gateways to red or amber would be to "red-gate" or "amber-gate" that employee. They are blocked from completing the process until the relevant issues have been addressed.

[Here](http://www.treasury.qld.gov.au/office/knowledge/docs/gateway-review-process-guidelines/gateway-review-guidebook.pdf)'s a document discussing it. See p10 for colour coding meaning. Basically red means immediate action required, amber means action required, but not immediately.

Comment: +1 I am very familar with RAG, more so with Project Management reporting. I now see how RAG gateways could be used in employee KPI management. I'll mark this answer correct in a day or two if there are no better answers.